# If Then Statement in Excel VBA for set range

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I have an `ActiveX ComboBox1` on `Sheet 1` that contains each month. I then have a row on the same sheet that contains a month in each cell `Range C7:N7`.  I would like to write a code that fills the cell in the next row `Range(C8:N8)` with data from cell `D14` on `Sheet 2` if `ComboBox1 = Range(C7:N7)`

The code would look similar to this:

```
If ComboBox1 = Range(B7, N7) Then
   Range(B8, N8) = "Sheet2!$D$14"
End If
```

Is this possible? Do I need to define something?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking for

Comment: I would like the cell on Sheet 2 to fill a corresponding cell on sheet 1 if the month selected in the ComboBox matches the month in row 7... does that make it clearer?

Comment: No. I still dont know what you are trying to do. Consider editing your question be clearer, show us your attempts, tell us what did not work

Comment: If the month in ComboBox1 = the month in row 7, cells B:N
then populate row 8, same column with cell D14 from Sheet 2

Comment: `if the month in comboxbox1` means what? number like 11? or name like "November"? `= the month in row 7, cells B:N` which means what? are you iterating to match against a value of each cell or what? and when and how are you firing that combox event? have you got a function for it? Were not mind-readers and its impossible to answer questions like yours.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, you can take advantage of the combobox's ListIndex property:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    'Clear prior entries
    Range("B8:N8").ClearContents

    'Make sure something has been selected in the listbox
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    'Populate the appropiate cell
    Range("B8").Offset(, ComboBox1.ListIndex).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D14").Value

End Sub
```